Angular finalize is not being called when using Behaviour Subject
I want to create a spinner every time user id is changed.
The content must change on the same page. But the finalize operator is not running and the spinner is forever spinning.
Is there an another aproach?
<button (click)="setUserId(1)">USER 1</button>
<button (click)="setUserId(2)">USER 2</button>

<section id="user-courses" *ngIf="!spinner.userCourses"></section>
<div *ngIf="spinner.userCourses">
    LOADING...
</div>

<section id="user-songs" *ngIf="!spinner.userSongs"></section>
<div *ngIf="spinner.userSongs">
    LOADING...
</div>

<section id="user-address" *ngIf="!spinner.userAddress"></section>
<div *ngIf="spinner.userAddress">
    LOADING...
</div>

public user$: BehaviorSubject<number | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

setUserId(id: number) {
  this.user$.next(id);
}

getUserId() {
  return this.user$.asObservable();
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getUserId().pipe(
    tap(r => this.spinner.userCourses = true),
    switchMap(userId => {
      this.courseService.getUserCourse(userId);
    }),
    finalize(() => this.spinner.userCourses = false)
  ).subscribe()

  this.getUserId().pipe(
    tap(r => this.spinner.userAddress = true),
    switchMap(userId => {
      this.addressService.getUserAddress(userId);
    }),
    finalize(() => this.spinner.userAddress = false)
  ).subscribe()

  this.getUserId().pipe(
    tap(r => this.spinner.userSongs = true),
    switchMap(userId => {
      this.songService.getUserFavoriteSongs(userId);
    }),
    finalize(() => this.spinner.userSongs = false)
  ).subscribe()
}


Does this answer your question? RxJS pipe Finalize operator not getting called

There's some missing/incorrect code in your example though (user$ is never defined and I assume there's supposed to be a return in that get function, for example) so there might be something else going on here depending on what you aren't showing. Although if I'm understanding what you're trying to do here, you might just want to use another tap instead of finalize.

Since user$ never completes, finalize will never be executed.  You could instead put the finalize call on the inner http call:
  this.user$.pipe(
    tap(r => this.spinner.userCourses = true),
    switchMap(userId => this.courseService.getUserCourse(userId).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.spinner.userCourses = false)        
    )),
  ).subscribe();

Alternatively, you could use an additional tap instead of finalize as suggested by @JohnMontgomery:
  this.user$.pipe(
    tap(r => this.spinner.userCourses = true),
    switchMap(userId => this.courseService.getUserCourse(userId))       
    tap(() => this.spinner.userCourses = false) 
  ).subscribe();

